# mapStateToProps must work with getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: react-native, redux

I've tried to use Redux in my react native application. I can definitely see that the value is updated by the reducers but my question is why it is not updating the properties of my class automatically?

I need to use getDerivedStateFromProps in order to populate my class properties. I expect that that the below:

> const mapStateToProps = (state) => {   return {  email: state.user }

will automatically update me this.state.email with the value from the redux store but  it doesn't. I need to doe the following to work:

> static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {return { user:
>   props.user}}

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly reducer in your component. It also update automatically when the value change in reducer. For example, if you want to use `user` variable in your component then you can use it as below :

```js
<Text>{this.props.user}</Text>
```

Now, when `user` variable value change in reducer, it automatically update in the `<Text>` component. You don't need to use this line :

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {return { user: props.user}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by directly use reducer? I did use reducer but it doesn't work

Comment: I means you don't need to assign redux variable `user` to state every time. You can use as like state variable.

Comment: oh i see... ok so that means the state really won't be updated automatically then? I just want to confirm this